# How to implement a security questionnaire using Azure B2C?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want the user to answer the questionnaire during sign-up, so if the user forgot the password, I could use the questionnaire, and in case all answers are right, it will let the user define a new password.

How to implement a security questionnaire using Azure B2C with a custom policy?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate a REST API call into your custom policy as one of the wrokflow steps.

This can shed some light or point you to the right direction:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-validation